# how to move filter outside of controller in angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, controller

I'm new in angular . i managed to filter using angular and it work fine but now i want to move filter outside of the controller which is quite challenging for me .

here is my html page :

```
<div >

    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="itemType('CAR')"/> CAR


    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="itemType('BIKE')"/> BIKE


    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="itemType('CYCLE')"/> CYCLE

</div>  
<table>
   <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterItem">
            <td >{{item.name}}</td>
            <td >{{item.type}}</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and controller :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.items = [
    {name: 'bmw', type:'CAR' },
    {name: 'ducati',type:'BIKE'},
    {name: 'airbas',type:'CYCLE' }
   ];

$scope.typeArray = [];
$scope.itemType = function(type) {
var i = $.inArray(type, $scope.typeArray);
if (i > -1) {
  $scope.typeArray.splice(i, 1);
} else {
  $scope.typeArray.push(type);
}
}

$scope.filterItem = function(item) {
if ($scope.typeArray.length > 0) {
  if ($.inArray(item.type, $scope.typeArray) < 0){
    return false;
  }
}
return item;
}
});
```

how can i move filtering from controller to app.filter().
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the custom filter is a separate module and you can write it as:

```
iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, types) {
    var filtered = [];

    var looping = function(name){
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
         if(item.type === name){
             filtered.push(item);
           }
        });
    }

      if(types.car == true){
        looping('CAR');
      }
      if(types.bike == true){
        looping('BIKE');
      }
      if(types.cycle == true){
        looping('CYCLE');
      }


    return filtered;
  };
});
```

*Controller:*

```
$scope.types = {car: false, bike:false, cycle: false};

   $scope.items = [
    {name: 'bmw', type:'CAR' },
    {name: 'ducati',type:'BIKE'},
    {name: 'airbas',type:'CYCLE' }
   ];
```

Demo 1 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQnbxyf7QUAk4HraUZMO?p=preview)</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

If you want to show all cells when no checkbox is selected, add this to filter:

```
  var flag = true;
  angular.forEach(types, function(type){
    flag = flag & !type; // if one of flags will be false, we get flag=false
  });

  if(flag == true){
    return items;
  }
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GgcC8Jf0KmEWNzoqs4Pz?p=preview)</kbd>

*FYI:* You can see that filters do not use `$scope`. If you want to pass additional argument the syntax should be:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myfilter:types">
```

where `types` is some object

Comment: how do you pass seleceted checkbox function  argument to filter ? it should be filtered depending selected checkbox .

Comment: you pass them around with ng-model attributes.

Comment: but i am using itemType() function not ng-model .could you plz explain  it a bit more ?

Comment: then just pass the array as a param, filterItem:typeArray

Comment: your code is reduntant though.  just connect checkboxes to filter with ng-model and you won't have to do all that array stuff in the back-end.

Comment: typeArray should be inside controller or filter ? ...jsfiddle or plunker will  appreciated

Comment: @nohan please understand one thing: the filter is only does filtering. I doesn't generate new array with different structure but the array with the same object items (after filtering you might get just less items). Otherwise you get limit digest cycle Exception. BTW, you don't need `typeArray` at all there. The condition information should be pass to filter module as argument.

Comment: Take a look on this example that uses custom filter with parameter: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0LMJzUiJy0NO9Hk0oWt?p=preview

Comment: @Maxim in above plunker example when i check both checkboxes it shows nothing but i want to show both types . thats way i created typeArray object .

Comment: its only condition. Just change `if` in filter. you dont need `typeArray`

Comment: i tried it .it's impossible to show two or three types by if statement . if you think its possible then plz modify above plunker and check it.

Comment: as i understand do you want to make checkboxes as reverse aka when none selected - table is clear; on both selected - all data is shown; right?

Comment: no . when one type selected it only shows  that types item and if two types are selected then it shows item of two types and if all three selected then it show all  items  and if nothing is selected its again shows all item.  my code  works fine but i just want to move it  into filter .

Comment: not yet . if nothing is selected it shows nothing but it should show all .not easy :(

Comment: else if(types.car == false && types.bike == false && types.cycle == false ){
        looping('CAR');
        looping('BIKE');
        looping('CYCLE');
      } .its a crazy solution . plz modify it so i will mark it as answer .